# Error when trying to connect TypeScript to Vue 3 project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli

When trying to add a useScroll  from the VueUse library to Vue 3 project, an error occurs in the browser

```
ERROR in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=template&id=7ba5bd90&ts=true (./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/App.vue?vue&type=template&id=7ba5bd90&ts=true) 3:27

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:27)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { resolveComponent as _resolveComponent, openBlock as _openBlock, createBlock as _createBlock } from "vue"
| 
> export function render(_ctx: any,_cache: any,$props: any,$setup: any,$data: any,$options: any) {
|   const _component_router_view = _resolveComponent("router-view")!
|
```

my App.vue

```
<template>

  <router-view ref="el"/>

</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useScroll } from '@vueuse/core'
import {ref} from "vue";

const el = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)
const { x, y, isScrolling, arrivedState, directions } = useScroll(el)
</script>
```

the error starts to occur when specifying the language (lang="ts"), without this the project loads as usual, but the directive does not work

my package.json

```
 {
  "name": "sibera",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vueuse/components": "^9.12.0",
    "@vueuse/core": "^9.12.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.0.24",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.58.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.14",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "@vue/typescript"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

I tried to remove node_modules and package.json and reinstall the project, but it didn't work...

Comment: You're missing `@vue/cli-plugin-typescript`

Comment: I installed it, but the error remained(((